# Overlaying two images with automatic resize using ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick

Is there are way to automatically resize the overlay image according to background size when overlaying images using ImageMagick? I am using the following code now:

> composite overlay.jpeg background.jpeg result.jpeg

The problem is that sometimes overlay and background are of different sizes, and I'd like to resize overlay accordingly (keeping the aspect ratio) and place it to the center. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, overlay and background do not need to be the same size for composite to work.  For example, given these two images:

sydney.png (352x288):

[image: sydney]

jet2.png (128x129):

[image: jet2]

Try the following commands:

```
convert -size 352x288 -composite sydney.png jet2.png -geometry 64x64+176+144 -depth 8 test.png

convert -size 352x288 -composite sydney.png jet2.png -geometry 32x32+176+144 -depth 8 test.png
```

- `-size` specifies the output image dimensions
- `-geometry` specifies the dimensions and location of the foreground

This is what I get for the first command:

[image: result]

**EDIT**

Here's a bash script to do it all for you in one line:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 background.png foreground.png output.png"
    exit 1
fi
bg_size=`identify -format '%wx%h' "$1"`
convert -size $bg_size -composite "$1" "$2" -geometry $bg_size+0+0 -depth 8 "$3"
```

Comment: So specify the same sizes to the `-size` and `-geometry` switches.  For example: `convert -size 352x288 -composite sydney.png jet2.png -geometry 352x288+0+0 -depth 8 test.png` will stretch the airplane to fit into the image window.

Comment: Well - this could work but I don't know the sizes of the image in advance so it would be nice if it could auto-stretch or whatever.

Comment: You can find the size of the images using the following bash command: `size=`identify -format '%wx%h' filename.png` and then work that into a bash script.  Imagemagick doesn't seem to have a `-autostretchorwhatever` switch, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok that's what I've just done - works beautifully, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  I went ahead and wrote you a script anyway -- see my updated answer.

Comment: @misha Thanks - exactly what I figured out as well. Thanks a ton for the tips!

Comment: u r a lifesaver.. I was getting crazy about how to achieve this.

Comment: I had to add the `-compose multiply` option to the command to get the desired blending result (IM version 6.9.5).

Comment: It's great! But how do I place foreground to the CENTER?