# combining few jpgs(and a txt) to a single jpg file

Tags: php, image-processing, filemerge

I have a sort of a canvas on my site, (not canvas though for the need of support in IE) where images are loaded to and modified.
At the end of the process I'd like to take all the files used in the canvas and connect them into a (bigger) jpg.
My thoughts were to collect all the relative positions of the images and use it to reposition them on the new file.
I should add as well that one of the files is a background image.
layers should not count more than lets say 4 including the background.
on top of that i needed to jpg-ize a text layer as well but for that I have a php script, if anyone has an efficient way to do it I'll be glad to see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [GD](http://php.net) or [ImageMagic](http://php.net/imagick) PHP extensions. Both allow to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802153/overlaying-two-images-with-automatic-resize-using-imagemagick) of how to do image overlays in imagemagick.  You can specify the scaling and position of the overlay in the `convert` parameters.