# Usage of value returned by 'identify' utility of ImageMagick in CMD

Tags: cmd, imagemagick, call, external, identify

A start of the line

```
identify -format %w input.jpg
```

in Command Prompt leads to printing of the width of the image.

I have to assign this value to some variable within a CMD-file in order to use this variable further in the script. How can I do this?

I need some code like this:

```
@echo OFF  
set width=identify -format %w input.jpg
rem ...further usage of %width%...
```

However, it doesn't work.

P.S.: The code presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803339/2199512) is almost what I need, but I need a code for the CMD-script.

Comment: the code to grab the output depends on the output.

Comment: When I start `identify -format %w input.jpg` from the command line, something like "1600" (I meen, just a number, an image width) on the next line is printed. I do not know, if this can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try this:

```
for /f %%a in ('identify -format %%w input.jpg') do set "width=%%~a"
echo %width%
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks a lot!